# Is there a way to directly analyze and manipulate tensorboard "events.*" log file?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

everyone. Tensorboard is a wonderful tool to visualize learning process, but it has some inconvenience for me. For some reason, sometimes I want to remove part of learning curve (like erase scalars after X-th step). However, all scalars are put together in a single "events.*" file, plus Tensorboard only provides high-level api  (only "adding" but no "removing") to the best of my knowledge. Does anyone have some ideas about this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can view the contents of a checkpoint file using `print_tensors_in_checkpoint_file()`,

```
from tensorflow.python.tools.inspect_checkpoint import print_tensors_in_checkpoint_file

print_tensors_in_checkpoint_file(file_name="<your_path_here>/model.ckpt-<whatever_step>", tensor_name='', all_tensors=True)
```